# React, Axios. Post request

Tags: reactjs, post, react-hooks, axios

I catch the input values, and add them to the date object. The problem is that the mail field is included in an internal object (data{data{mail:""}}). Below is my code, I don't understand how to add a value to an internal object.

```
const data = {object_type: "person", name: "", object_code: "", data: {}} //add here
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState(data)

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputData({...inputData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    console.log(e.target.name)
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.post(url, inputData)
      .then((response)=> {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }

 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="create-form-name">
        Имя
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value={inputData.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="create-form-name">
        Телефон
        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="object_code" value={inputData.object_code} onChange={handleChange}/>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="create-form-name">
        Электронный адрес
        <input id="mail" type="email" name={data.data.mail} /* value={inputData.data.data} */ onChange={handleChange}/>
      </label>
      <button className="button-create-contact" type="submit">Создать</button>
    </form>
```

I thought about making more constants, but it seems like a bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You can try this-

```
<input id="mail" type="email" name='mail' value={inputData.data.mail} onChange={
(e)=>{
setInputData({...inputData.data, mail: e.target.value })
}}/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. In the react documentation I found the following
```function handleTitleChange(e) {setPerson({...person,artwork: {...person.artwork,title: e.target.value } });}```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [inputData, setInputData] = useState({object_type: "person", name: "", object_code: "", data: {mail:""}})


  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputData({...inputData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }

  const handleMailChange = (e) => {
    setInputData({...inputData, data: {...inputData.data, mail: e.target.value}})
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    /* e.preventDefault(); */
    axios.post(url, inputData)
      .then((response)=> {
        console.log(response)
      })
  }

  return(
    <>
    <div className="create-panel">
      <h2>Заполнение анкеты для нового контакта</h2>
    </div>
    <div className="create-form">
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="create-form-name">
        Имя*
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name" value={inputData.name} onChange={handleChange} required/>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="create-form-name">
        Телефон*
        <input id="phone" type="tel" name="object_code" value={inputData.object_code} onChange={handleChange} required/>
      </label>
      <label htmlFor="create-form-name">
        Электронный адрес
        <input id="mail" type="email" name="mail" value={inputData.data.mail} onChange={handleMailChange}/>
      </label>
      <button className="button-create-contact" type="submit">Создать</button>
    </form>
    {/* <button style={{border:"1px solid black", padding:"5px"}} onClick={() => {
      console.log(inputData)
      }}>Click</button> */}
    </div>
    </>
  )
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).